# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat - Tuesday 02:00 UTC  / Monday 9pm EST

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 31st at 02:00 UTC.  *This is Monday 9pm EST!***

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=1&day=31&year=2012&hour=2&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2321/town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary (or actual election if there is no primary) phase.  This means that I am looking at the 30th-1st. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=scifi.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: We need to know sooner rather than later when this chat is going to happen. Some of the folks who are running have to change their plans to accommodate this chat.

Comment: I'm updating things right now actually. (:

Answer (score 7):

Just a thought for future elections. It might be better to try and time the nomination phase so that at least part of the chat options fall on a weekend, for those of us (which, I would think, is most) who have work during the day; the workday limits my availability quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

I third the desire to have this on a weekend. Also, the selected time might allow the most participation from the *candidates*, but does it allow the most participation from the *electorate*? For me (in the UK), it's at 2am, for Europeans it's 3am. This is a global, 24/7 site and all users should have the opportunity to put questions to the candidates.

It feels like Rebecca's announcement is missing a sign that says 'Americans only' :-(

Comment: It's 3am for me too. If you have questions, please post them on [this meta thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/2012-moderator-election-ask-the-candidates) before the chat (so that someone can ask them for you) or after the chat (if they haven't been covered).

Comment: @Gilles Excellent work, really good idea!

Comment: Some of the candidates might actually take a peek at that meta thread just before the town hall chat starts. So do add your questions there if you can't make it.

Comment: It's not possible to find a time of day that will suit everyone around the world; e.g. any time that's good for both Europe and the Americas will be bad for us in Asia/Pacific.  The only way to handle this would be to have two chats.

Answer (score 1):

The first would work for me, the 30th would be okay, but not great. The best times would be UTC times 100-400 sometime (So, I guess technically it would be the next day for each of those days).

Answer (score 1):

I second the desire to have this on a weekend.  But, since that's not happening, I'm free on both days, UTC 0000-0400.  I'm in the US, Central Time Zone.

Answer (score 0):

Alright for me.. Its 7:30 AM in my time zone!