# Images have an unnecessary 1em bottom margin

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Images on this site have an unnecessary bottom margin of 1em, which leads to them being weirdly offset when inline with text, as seen in [the Town Hall Digest](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1390/4501).

Even when not inline with text, the margin compounds with the bottom margin of the generated `<p>` elements in posts, causing an extra wide gap between the image and the next paragraph ([example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10094/does-namor-the-sub-mariner-still-possess-the-powers-of-all-sea-creatures)).

This used to [be the case on DBA](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=731412#731412) as well, but the margin has since been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed in the next build. The `img` styles are next to the `h1...h3` styles (which have that margin); I assume that's why they were accidentally added to the images as well.