# When's the Town Hall chat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

There's [an election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election) that just started.  Part of it will be a Town Hall chat.  That page helpfully announces:

> A Town Hall Chat with the candidates will take place Tuesday the 31st at 02:00 UTC.

Of course, there is no Feb 31st.  And looking at other clues on the page doesn't help.  The election starts in 7 days, which would be next Monday, the 25th.  It's going to end on March 5th, which is 8 days after the 25th.  So, does this mean the Town Hall is next week on Tuesday?  That'd make it 1 day into the election proper, which seems a bit early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry; there's only one election post, shared between elections, so [as Tim noted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2687/1586) that's a carry-over from last year.

I've updated the election page to reflect the resources *currently* available.

Answer (score 2):

The town hall chat for this election hasn't been scheduled yet. In a few days a post will go up here on meta announcing the chat, and once the candidates have provided their availability, the post will be updated with the selected date and time.

Apparently that notice text isn't specific to the current election, and is actually [carry over](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-tuesday-0200-utc-monday-9pm-est) from when the election was held last year.